How can I configure Google Chrome so that whenever I visit a given subdomain on a given site it redirects to another subdomain on the same given site?
How can I configure Google Chrome so that whenever I visit a given subdomain on a given site (e.g., www.reddit.com) it always redirects to another subdomain on the same given site (e.g., old.reddit.com)?

There were plugins that did this. Can you share with us the research you've done and what you've tried?

A quick web search showed there are Chrome plugins, updated to Manifest v3, so still valid, that do this: https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/old-reddit-redirect/dneaehbmnbhcippjikoajpoabadpodje
To use this, it appears you only have to install and activate the plugin.
This one specifically redirects Reddit.com to Old.Reddit.com. There are a variety of plugins that promise more general redirection capabilities, but the ones I looked at specifically have not been updated in a while, are unlikely to be compatible with Manifest v3, and it is a question whether they still work or will work in the near future.
